# ef core 5 InMemory testing

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit

I'm working on migration from net core 3.1 to net 5
With net core 3.1 testing repositories that uses ef core was passing but after upgrading to net core 5, SaveChanges on dbContext throw nullreferenceException

Here is the stack trace

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`2.<SanitizeConverter>b__0(Object v)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTable`1.SnapshotValue(IProperty property, ValueComparer comparer, IUpdateEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTable`1.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Create>b__0(IProperty p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTable`1.Create(IUpdateEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryStore.ExecuteTransaction(IList`1 entries, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 updateLogger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

The dbContext for tests is created with these options

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DcmCockpitDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .Options;

            using (_context = new DcmCockpitDbContext(options, null))
            {
                SeedDatabase(_context);
            }
```

Is there any breaking changes that throw  this exception ?
What should i do to avoid this ?

Comment: This is the only breaking change that seems applicable. Could you have some code like this in your tests? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#no-client-methods

Answer (score 0):

After long debugging sessions, the probleme come from missing dependencies.